# Automatic gpg signature verification and decryption with gnus

Tags: gnus, gpg

I am trying to use Gnus for sending and receiving gpg signed/encrypted emails. I am following these tutorials for the setup etc.

- https://github.com/kensanata/ggg
- https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org

By the way, I am using this Emacs setup as well:

- https://github.com/purcell/emacs.d

However, **signed/encrypted emails are not verified/decrypted automatically when I open them**, and I cannot figure out how to setup this.
I beleive that this manual page contains some clues, but still I don't see how to include them in the setup:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Security.html#Security